# Red bug with white tips on antennae

Tags: species-identification, entomology

These red bugs can be found in hundreds in our locality in Bangalore, India.

They are just about 3.5 cm and have these white (or maybe pale yellow) tips on their antennae.

[image]

Can someone identify them and suggest a link where I can find substantial information on their morphology and general behaviour?

Comment: *What's That Bug?* (https://www.whatsthatbug.com/) is another great place to ask for bug identifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has an answer (previously) already accepted and upvoted. However, the identification is incorrect.

This insect belongs to other Genus, *[Melamphaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melamphaus)*. Here is an image of *Melamphaus sp*:

[image]

The image in the (previously) accepted answer is, in fact, an image of *Melamphaus*, not *Antilochus*. What probably happened is that the source (a blog) whose image was copied is wrong. The fact that the blog got the epithet wrong (*conqueberti* instead of *coquebertii*) corroborates this.

For comparison, here is an image of *Antilochus coquebertii* from a [reliable source](http://www.entomoljournal.com/vol3Issue1/pdf/3-1-61.1.pdf), the Journal of Entomology and Zoology Studies:

[image]

Comment: Wow... Good job with this correction! +1

Answer (score 15):

I think they are called "Red Bugs" (really), otherwise known as [Antilochus conquebertii](https://derabiodiversity.blogspot.com/2016/05/antilochus-conqueberti.html) (aka Antilochus coquebertii).

[image]

The black coloring changes from location to location. These were found in India. They were even described by the querent as eating black seeds.

[Viet Nam](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2013/01/07/mating-red-bugs-from-viet-nam/) Red Bugs are pretty as well:

[image]

> The family Pyrrhocoridae is commonly called the Red Bug family, and the family includes the Cotton Stainers as well as the Firebugs, so Red Bugs is the more general family name that includes the other genera and species.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I think it's A.conquebertii, with a double 'i' . Also where can I find some information on them?

Comment: @AdDate, [Google is your friend.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Antilochus+conquebertii)

Comment: I didn't find much though. I want some more details.

Comment: *Antilochus* is a sister clade of *Pyrrhocoris* which we call "fire bugs" (or "gendarme" in french). You'll easily find more info for *Pyrrhocoris*.

Comment: @AdDate Note by the way, that it is more polite to say "I would like" than "I want".

Comment: It is also spelled without the "n" in "conquebertii": Antilochus coquebertii.  When I google that name, I get 2000 results, compared to 170 for the other name.  And that is what is used on the (sparse) Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilochus_coquebertii

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle - Thanks so much! That is a great help. I'll edit that into my answer.